# Como bloquear botones dando clic a otro botón

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net

Hola buenas comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema ya no encuentro la mejor manera de solucionarlo de antemano muchas gracias.

Tengo una aplicación web donde un usuario entra a la pagina inserta sus datos a través de una modal popup a la base de datos y se muestran sus datos insertados.

Por otro lado entra otro usuario al mismo formulario este puede actualizar los datos que el usuario anterior inserto. La novedad de este usuario es que se le aparece un botón. Este botón tiene la finalidad de:

> Cerrar Registros: Bloquea los botones de la modal del primer usuario para que no pueda insertar mas registros.
>
> Abrir Registros: Desbloquea los botones de la modal del primer usuario para que pueda insertar nuevamente registros.

Cerrar Registros y Abrir Registros debe realizarse con el mismo botón.

El bloqueo de botones debe persistir para que cuando el segundo usuario bloquee los botones el primer usuario al momento de entrar debe tener bloqueado botones de la modal y no pueda insertar registros. Del mismo modo cuando el segundo usuario desbloquee los botones el primer usuario debe tener desbloqueados los botones.

Trabajo con periodos así que no se como hacer este bloqueo y desbloqueo ya que si bloqueo todos los botones de la modal al seleccionar otro periodo distinto estos botones aparecerán bloqueados, es por ello que no se como trabajarlo si con base de datos o usando local storage. Espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: La manera mas sencilla es que desde base de datos agregues un campo para verificar que tu registro no esta siendo modificado eso de bloquear los botones no te servira a menos que constantemente estes verificando que alguien mas no esta usando el mismo registro. Ejemplo tu campo puede ser FechaHoraActualizacion a la hora de guardar puedes verificar que el registro que estas enviando tenga la misma FechaHoraActualizacion que se encuentra en BD asi sabras que nadie mas ha modificado un registro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi consejo personal es que almacenes toda la información en una base de datos, con una tabla de usuarios. Al dar click al botón por el "Usuario administrador", puedes hacer un update a la base de datos, en donde deshabilites los permisos del "Usuario Normal". Eso como opción 1.
 La opción 2, es seguir con base de datos, pero agregar las tablas de "Tipo de usuario", y "Permisos". En donde podrás ir ajustando según tus propias necesidades, que botones quieres que la persona vea o no. Por ejemplo, puedes deshabilitar con JQuery el botón, según lo que JQuery lea desde la base de datos. Esta linea de codigo de JQuery puede servirte:

```
$(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Saludos! Y cualquier duda, comenta acá para ayudar.

Nota: La solución está pensada siempre y cuando tu backend esté retornando valores al front directamente, y no si es que usas un framework con motor de vistas.

Answer (score 1):

Interesante problema, lo que se me ocurre es lo siguiente

Si un usuario abre un modal, el tu front debe comunicarle a tu back que se ha abierto un modal de un dato especifico y en tu base de datos (o donde manejes los datos de este usuario) crear una especie de bandera

Ej: si es 0 el registro no esta en uso por nadie, cuando se habra el modal cambias la bandera a 1 de esta forma cuando otro usuario intenta acceder a los datos queda a tu criterio mostrar un mensaje de tipo "Registro en uso" o bloqueado los botones que desees.

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La única forma es que persistas el estatus en tu base de datos, al hacer click en el botón debes desatar el evento que modifique esa propiedad de la instancia en BD.

```
const areRecordsOpen = status => !status;

console.log(areRecordsOpen(true)) // must be false
```